# Selecting first and last time stamps of a section

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, aggregate-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a MySQL database with a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE example (Batch_Num int, Time_Stamp datetime);
INSERT INTO example VALUES
    (1, '2020-12-10 16:37:43'),
    (1, '2020-12-11 09:47:31'),
    (1, '2020-12-11 14:02:17'),
    (1, '2020-12-11 15:28:02'),
    (2, '2020-12-12 15:08:52'),
    (2, '2020-12-14 10:38:02'),
    (2, '2020-12-14 16:22:35'),
    (2, '2020-12-15 08:44:13'),
    (3, '2020-12-16 11:38:05'),
    (3, '2020-12-17 10:19:13'),
    (3, '2020-12-17 14:45:28');

+-----------+-----------------------+
| Batch_Num |      Time_Stamp       |
+-----------+-----------------------+
|         1 | '2020-12-10 16:37:43' |
|         1 | '2020-12-11 09:47:31' |
|         1 | '2020-12-11 14:02:17' |
|         1 | '2020-12-11 15:28:02' |
|         2 | '2020-12-12 15:08:52' |
|         2 | '2020-12-14 10:38:02' |
|         2 | '2020-12-14 16:22:35' |
|         2 | '2020-12-15 08:44:13' |
|         3 | '2020-12-16 11:38:05' |
|         3 | '2020-12-17 10:19:13' |
|         3 | '2020-12-17 14:45:28' |
+-----------+-----------------------+
```

I would like to select from this table the first and last timestamp for each value of each Batch_Number. I would like the table to look like:

```
+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| Batch_Num | Beginning_Time_Stamp  |    End_Time_Stamp     |
+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|         1 | '2020-12-10 16:37:43' | '2020-12-11 15:28:02' |
|         2 | '2020-12-12 15:08:52' | '2020-12-15 08:44:13' |
|         3 | '2020-12-16 11:38:05' | '2020-12-17 14:45:28' |
+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

I am not sure how to select both, when the previous Batch_Num is different from the curent one, and also when the next one is different.

Comment: For the data you actually did show us, basic aggregation is just fine.  If you do need a gaps and islands solution, then show data which reveals that (and see the @GMB answer below in that case).

Comment: I have no repeating batch numbers so your solution worked fine, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic `GROUP BY` query should work here:

```sql
SELECT
    Batch_Num,
    MIN(Time_Stamp) AS Beginning_Time_Stamp,
    MAX(Time_Stamp) AS End_Time_Stamp
FROM example
GROUP BY
    Batch_Num
ORDER BY
    Batch_Num;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

If the same batch number might appear in different series, then aggrgaation alone cannot solve the problem. You would typically approach this with some gaps-and-island technique; here, a simple approach uses the difference between row numbers to identify groups of adjacent records (islands):

```
select batch_num, 
    min(time_stamp) as start_time_stamp, 
    max(time_stamp) as end_time_stamp,
    count(*) as cnt
from (
    select e.*,
        row_number() over(order by time_stamp) as rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by batch_num order by time_stamp) as rn2
    from example e
) t
group by batch_num, rn1 - rn2
order by start_time_stamp
```

Here is **[a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c9c977efef9793ea1f18d0175b7cde4)**. I added a new occurence of batch `1` at the end of the dataset:

```
batch_num | start_time_stamp    | end_time_stamp      | cnt
--------: | :------------------ | :------------------ | --:
        1 | 2020-12-10 16:37:43 | 2020-12-11 15:28:02 |   4
        2 | 2020-12-12 15:08:52 | 2020-12-15 08:44:13 |   4
        3 | 2020-12-16 11:38:05 | 2020-12-17 14:45:28 |   3
        1 | 2020-12-18 14:02:17 | 2020-12-18 15:28:02 |   2
```